# How do I save multiple selections from List to EF Model?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to learn how to submit multiple selections from a list to the model created between two data models. I have tried the following:

```
                var tag = context.TagInformation.Find(model.Tags[0]);
                var newlyCreatedUser = context.Users.Find(user.Id);
                newlyCreatedUser.TagInfo = new List<TagInformation>(0) { tag };
                context.SaveChanges();
```

I have also tried the following:

```
                var tags = new List<TagInformation>();
                foreach (var tag in model.Tags)
                {
                    var tag= context.TagInformation.Find(model.Tags[0]);
                    if (tag != null)
                    {
                        tags.Add(tag);
                    }
                }
                var newlyCreatedUser = context.Users.Find(user.Id);
                newlyCreatedUser.TagInfo = tags;
                context.SaveChanges();
```

I have searched on Google and tried to find what value I need to change here in order to save all selected values from model.Tags, but currently only the first selected value is saved. To my understanding, the [0] is causing it to only save the first selected tag. I need to automatically save any combination of selected tags from the List, regardless of how many tags are in the list.

I can see that all of the select tags are loaded during debugging, and the foreach statement gets passed through for each selected id, but still only saves the first tag selected in the list.

What must I change to obtain this result and where can I find documentation to help me understand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tag= context.TagInformation.Find(model.Tags[0]);
```

this line of code always select the first tag, you should do something like

```
var tag= context.TagInformation.Find(tag);
```